# Testing if a Daemon is alive or not with Shell

Tags: shell

I have a log_sender.pl perl script that when executed runs a daemon. I want to make  a test, using Shell:

```
 #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                              

 function log_sender()
 {
     perl -I $HOME/script/log_sender.pl
 }

 (
   [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" == "${0}" ]] || exit 0
   function check_log_sender()
      {
          if [ "ps -aef | grep -v grep log_sender.pl" ]; then
              echo "PASSED"
              else
              echo FAILED
          fi
     }


     log_sender
     check_log_sender

 )
```

Unfortunately when I run this my terminal becomes:

```
 -bash-4.1$ sh log_sender.sh 
 ...   
 ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> if [ "ps -aef | grep -v grep log_sender.pl" ]; then
```

This is certainly not what you want.  Try this:

```
if ps -aef | grep -q 'log_sender\.pl'; then
    ...
```

In a shell script, the `if` construct takes as its argument a command whose exit status it examines.  In your code, the command is `[` (also known as `test`) and you run it on the literal string `"ps -aef | grep -v grep log_sender.pl"` which is simply always true.

You probably intended to check whether `ps -aef` outputs a line which contains `log_sender.pl` but does not contain `grep`; that would be something like `ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep 'log_sender\.pl'` but you can avoid the extra `grep -v` by specifying a regular expression which does not match itself.

The `-q` option to `grep` suppresses any output; the exit code indicates whether or not the input matched the regular expression.

The `perl` invocation is also not correct; the `-I` option requires an argument, so you are saying effectively just `perl` and your Perl interpreter is now waiting for you to type in a Perl script for it to execute.  Apparently the script is `log_sender.pl` so you should simply drop the `-I` (or add an argument to it, if you really do need to add some Perl library paths in order for the script to work).

Finally, if you write a Bash script, you should execute it with Bash.

```
chmod +x log_sender.sh
./log_sender.sh
```

or alternatively

```
bash ./log_sender.sh
```

The `BASH_SOURCE` construct you use is a Bashism, so your script will simply not work correctly under `sh`.

Finally, the parentheses around the main logic are completely redundant.  They will cause the script to run these commands in a separate subshell for no apparent benefit.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what I meant to do with the grep -v grep construction, avoid matching the grep as well. But your construction is much cleaner. I notice that when I run it both from bash or using sh, nothing appears in the terminal screen but if I do CONTROL+D (in Mac), then the result appears...